# Convert custom duration string to moment duration for comparison

Tags: typescript, momentjs, primeng, duration

For a custom sort function in a table, I need a function that can compare two duration strings. These are in a custom format.

Here's the function I use to convert milliseconds to the string. The `seconds` boolean is there so I can ignore the seconds part if needed.

```
export function convertMillisecondsToHours(
  milliseconds: number,
  seconds: boolean
): string {
  if (seconds)
    return `${moment
      .duration(milliseconds)
      .format('d [d] hh [h] mm [min] ss [s]')}`;
  else
    return `${moment.duration(milliseconds).format('d [d] hh [h] mm [min]')}`;
}
```

Resulting strings look like this, for example: `1 d 21 h 59 mins`.

Now, in my table (PrimeNG, but that is not that important) I need a custom sort function that is able to sort this kind of duration from shortest to longest. My idea is to convert it to a moment.js date or duration and diff/subtract. Here's what I got (which fails at the conversion part):

```
 customSort(event: SortEvent) {
    console.log(`Sorting`)
    event.data.sort((data1, data2) => {
      let value1: string = data1[event.field];
      let value2: string = data2[event.field];

      // Convert to moment date/duration, compare (subtract/diff) and return value.
      const date1 = moment.duration(value1)
      const date2 = moment.duration(value2)
      return (event.order * date2.subtract(date1).asMilliseconds());
    });
  }
```

Converted dates are invalid right now. How can I convert my custom duration string back to a date or unix timestamp I can use in a compare function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I wrote my own function.

```ts
/**
 * Converts a duration string from the table to milliseconds.
 * @param durationString The duration string in format d [d] hh [h] mm [min] ss [s] or d [d] hh [h] mm [min]
 */
export function customDurationStringToMilliseconds(durationString: string): number {
  let duration = 0;

  // Add days.
  if (durationString.includes('d')) {
    duration +=
      parseInt(durationString.substr(0, durationString.indexOf('d')), 10) *
      86400;
    durationString = durationString.replace(
      durationString.substring(0, durationString.indexOf('d') + 1),
      ''
    );
  }

  // Add hours.
  if (durationString.includes('h')) {
    duration +=
      parseInt(durationString.substr(0, durationString.indexOf('h')), 10) *
      3600;
    durationString = durationString.replace(
      durationString.substring(0, durationString.indexOf('h') + 1),
      ''
    );
  }

  // Add minutes.
  if (durationString.includes('min') || durationString.includes('mins')) {
    duration +=
      parseInt(durationString.substr(0, durationString.indexOf('min')), 10) *
      60;
    if (durationString.includes('mins'))
      durationString = durationString.replace(
        durationString.substring(0, durationString.indexOf('mins') + 4),
        ''
      );
    else
      durationString = durationString.replace(
        durationString.substring(0, durationString.indexOf('min') + 3),
        ''
      );
  }

  // Add seconds.
  if (durationString.includes('s')) {
    duration += parseInt(
      durationString.substr(0, durationString.indexOf('s')),
      10
    );
  }
  return duration;
}
```

Probably not the most elegant solution, but it works. Sorting:

```ts
export function customSort(event: SortEvent) {
    event.data.sort((data1, data2) => {
          const value1: string = data1[event.field];
          const value2: string = data2[event.field];
          return (
            event.order *
            (customDurationStringToMilliseconds(value1) -
            customDurationStringToMilliseconds(value2))
        );
    });
}
```